# how to query by the user for a model in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model for status. It displays all the status nicely. Now what I want is to display all the status or the activities of a particular user in the user's page. How do I query all the `status` and the `liked status` for a particular user?

Please correct me if I am wrong. I tried this in the shell, but its showing empty :

```
>>> from status.models import *
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> s = Status.objects.get(id=3)
>>> s
<Status: sdfjsdklsdf>
>>> s.creator
<User: test2@gmail.com>
>>> u = User.objects.get(id=6)
>>> u
<User: test2@gmail.com>
>>> u.status_set.all()
[]
>>>
```

Here's my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime
from time import time


def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" %(str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)

class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="creator_set")
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Like")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
        verbose_name_plural = ('Status')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.status

class Like(models.Model):
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
    liked = models.ForeignKey(User)
    liked_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s likes %s" % (self.liked, self.status)
```

Please check and guide me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
u.creator_set.all()
```

Notice, you have put `related_name=creator_set` on the FK.

Edited:
Get the Like for the user:

```
u.like_set.all()
```

And if you want the corresponding status for the likes:

```
[each.status for each in u.like_set.all()]
```

Comment: Thanks, and how do I query for the likes status that the user has liked?

Comment: Thank you! By the way can you please explain me the last line.

Comment: You are getting all the `Like` objects for a user and then doing a list comprehension to get status for each instance of `Like`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Status.objects.filter(creator__id=6)
Like.objects.filter(liked__id=6)
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I query for the logged in user?

Comment: if request.user.is_authenticated():
  Status.objects.filter(creator=request.user)